# Are there different uses of the arrow mark '->' used by pointers in C++? How exactly is it used?

Tags: c++, object, pointers

Are there different uses of the `->` symbol? (I think it's called overloading).

One of them that I know is that a pointer uses it to access a member of the object to which the pointer points to. For example:

```cpp
class fruit{
      char colour[10];
};

fruit mango;
fruit *pointertofruit = &mango;  // Will it work without using the '&'?
pointertofruit->colour = '______';
```

Can I take it that the pointer is telling that "**I point to an object whose data member is 'colour', so allow me to make that '______'**"?

Comment: `a->b` usually means `(*a).b`. It doesn't mean `a` points to `b`.

Answer (score 2):

There are two uses for `->`:

- it dereferences a raw pointer to access a member (as you describe).
- it is an operator that a [class/struct can overload](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) to return whatever it wants, as long as that something can also be dereferenced by `->`.  This is *most commonly* done in smart-pointer classes, like `std::unique_ptr`/`std::shared_ptr`, `CComPtr`/`CComQIPtr`, etc to dereference an internally held pointer, eg:

```cpp
class fruit_ptr {
    fruit *m_f;
public:
    fruit_ptr(fruit *f) : m_f(f) {}
    ~fruit_ptr() { delete m_f; }
    fruit* operator->(){ return m_f; }
};

fruit_ptr pointertofruit(new mango);
pointertofruit->colour = ...; // calls: pointertofruit.operator->()->colour = ...;
```